# wsgi_mod.so compiled for python2.7 on OS X Apache not starting

Tags: mamp, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to get a Django 1.4.3 project running on my local machine, a MacBook Pro running High Sierra, and Mamp 4.5. The project is currently running on a Linux box with Python2.6 installed.

Python2.6 seems to be pretty much obsolete so I'm using Python2.7, in a venv locally.

I've compiled a new wsgi_mod.so using the instructions from here:

```
https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-on-macosx.html
```

I've copied the new file to the modules directory (moved the original file), but apache will not start now, I also notice that the new file is only 239b in size, the original wsgi_mod.so, which came with Mamp, is 2.2m.

Edit:

When I run: `./configure --with-apxs=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apxs`

I get the following error:

```
checking Apache version... cannot open /Applications/MAMP/Library/build/config_vars.mk: No such file or directory at /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apxs line 217
```

If I run: `./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/bin/apxs --with-python=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`

Still the same outcome, same small file and apache wont start.

I realised that I could try to fire apache up from the command line, which would provide more feedback than the graphical MAMP tool:

Running `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start`

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 132 of /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf: Cannot load /Applications/MAMP/Library/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/Library/modules/mod_wsgi.so, 10): Symbol not found: _ap_unixd_config\n  Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/Library/modules/mod_wsgi.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /Applications/MAMP/Library/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Comment: You need to show what error messages are from the Apache error log for a start. But yes the size doesn't look right. You might instead try the ``pip install`` method. See https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi/

Comment: That's for commenting, unfortunately, there are no error log messages, if MAMP doesn't start it doesn't write a log

Comment: I tried pip install first, but get same outcome.

Comment: Hi @GrahamDumpleton, I've edited the OP, with an error message!

Comment: That usually indicates that mod_wsgi was compiled against header files for a version of Apache different to what it was being loaded into at runtime. Some of those MAMP packages for Apache on macOS don't actually even supply header files and so it may be find header files from different Apache installation.

Comment: Any reason you can't use the Apache that comes with macOS?

Comment: MAMP comes with Apache 2.2, so I thought it may be an apache version error.

Comment: I think compiling with Apache 2.4 has fixed it! I would prefer to use MAMP apache,  any advice on how would be welcome